# Get rid of these control characters in the code editor for Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode11, xcode11.3

In Xcode 11.3.1 (11C505), I have accidentally enabled the ability to see control characters, such as these carriage returns or dots on my code:

[image]

How do I hide these from the editor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can turn it off with Editor -> Invisibles

[image]